# Как удалить конкретный файл из корзины Windows

Tags: python, windows

Как удалить один конкретный файл из корзины через Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться библиотекой winshell чтобы удалить все файлы с корзины при помощи метода empty

```
import winshell
winshell.recycle_bin().empty(confirm=False, show_progress=False, sound=False)
```

Если необходимо удалить один файл:

```
import os, winshell

r = winshell.recycle_bin()

for file in r:
    if "filename" in file.original_filename():
        os.remove(file.filename())
```

Comment: OS - Windows, нужно удалять всего 1 файл.